# Codeigniter 3 and session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

I had sessions working fine in 2.x version of CI. I used to save them using default CI session option (browser I believe), but I've decided to use database now. I've setup table and everything else in config file. Problem is I never get any errors. Session and encryption library are in autoload config file. In my model I use following code to put data into session:

```
$this->session->set_userdata(array(
  'email' => $email,
  'is_logged_in' => 1)
);
```

But when I try to use:

```
var_dump($this->session->userdata());
```

I get following output:

```
array(1) { ["__ci_last_regenerate"]=> int(1448664996) }
```

nothing is added to session, no errors showing up. Can anyone help?

EDIT:

config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'mydomain';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'email', 'encryption', 'session');
```

I've followed all instructions documentation is showing.

EDIT 2:

controller:

```
public function login_into_site()
    {
        if($this->input->post('viaAjax') == 1)
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email|callback_validate_credentials');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5|trim');
            $user_url = base64_decode($this->input->post('rand'));

            if ($this->form_validation->run())
            {
                $sulo = array();
                $sulo['res'] = '1';
                $sulo['address'] = $user_url;
                echo json_encode($sulo);
            }
            else
            {
                $formError = array();
                $formError['email'] = form_error('email');
                $formError['password'] = form_error('password');
                echo json_encode($formError);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo json_encode("fail");
        }
    }

    public function validate_credentials()
    {
        $this->load->model('user/model_user_auth');
        $this->model_user_auth->can_log_in($message);
        if($message == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if($message == 2)
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_credentials','not activated');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_credentials','bad username or password');
            return false;
        }
    }
```

model:

```
public function can_log_in(&$message)
    {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $this->db->where('email',$email);
        $this->db->where('password',md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        $message = '';
        if($query->num_rows() == 1)
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                'email' => $email,
                'is_logged_in' => 1)
            );

            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
                $activated = $row->activate;
                $membership = $row->membership;
            }
            if($activated == NULL && $membership == 'a')
            {
                $message = 1; //success
            }
            else if($activated != NULL && $membership == 'a')
            {
                $message = 2; //not activated
            }
            else
            {
                $message = 3; // user exist but info wrong
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $message = 0; // user does not exist
        }
    }
```

Model generates `$message = 1;` because I get return as "TRUE" in controller callback function and controller function that loges user in proceed without any errors

Comment: The table you create, is it for CI2 or CI3?

Comment: @Tpojka for CI3. I got it from https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Why did you mention CI2?

Comment: @Tpojka "I had sessions working fine in 2.x version of CI", used to work in 2.x no in 3 does not work

Comment: @Tpojka I've added config info if that may help. Reason why I am puzzled is because code looks ok, there are no errors, but it is not saving session info. Rest of the code executes just fine. Even if I put `$_SESSION['email'] = $email` it does not work, but if I put `session_start();` I get an error that session already started

Comment: Rest of controller code would help. Everything here seems fine.

Comment: @Tpojka I've added controller and model code.

Comment: Pass an argument to callback function that should represent string from form rule. [Docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods).

Comment: @Tpojka even without that it does not work. I've put that after it didn't work to test out results, did not help. But now when it is deleted again it does not work

Comment: You have to return `$message` from model. You don't need reference there. Also, you don't have to pass it from controller since you are using Input class in model.

Comment: @Tpojka $message goes back to validate_credentials() and if it is 1 return TRUE, which works exactly the way it should, I think I don't understand what are you trying to say

Comment: Bit strange concept to me. I would have it like `$message = $this->model_user_auth->can_log_in();` Than in model, at the end `return $message;` what ever that value becomes during model operations.

Comment: @Tpojka good point. I've changed that, but still it proceed without errors, but puts nothing in session.

Comment: Please make test method in controller with setting session key value and var dump it to determine if session is ok. If it is, issue is in form and/or model.

Comment: @Tpojka so when I found out problem, sort of. With my model works just fine. So when my session is set if I create following in my controller: `$sulo['test'] = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
$sulo['test2'] = $this->session->userdata('email');` those information are retreived, I can see result of json, but as soon as my page is redirected it looks like session gets flushed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. Problem was that my cookie was overriding database session. In config file if using database for session, this line cannot have value"

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'mydomain';
```

In order for session to work using database, that value has to be empty:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = '';
```

If it is not empty, CI will default to cookies for your session. This does not mean you cannot use cookies. You just have to loaded them via helper and they will work just fine.

Comment: Would you please state your source of this information? I am using redis sessions and storing the session ID in a cookie with a name, all works just great. Would love to learn more about your point mentioned above.